# Want to configure build.gradle so that artifcatory user and pass are worked in both local and in Jenkins

Tags: gradle

So basically this is what I want, I want to configure the artifactory server in build.gradle file like

```
Artifcatory {
    Contexturl = ***
      Resolve{
          Repository {
               Repokey = **
               Username = $artuser
               Password= $artpass
        }
  }
```

}

And I have put the artuser and artpass in the gradle.properties file in my local machine. But if I try it in Jenkins it will not be able to find the properties artuser and artpass

So currently I have 2 build.gradle file one for local and one for Jenkins which is not having this artifcatory configuration. But configuring it in the build stage. so is there a way I could use only one build.gradle file so that it will work in both cases

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the credentials plugin on Jenkins to manage credentials, and then pass them as environment variables to gradle. That way, there is no need to put the credentials in clear text on the build server.

If you are using declarative Jenkinsfile, you can pass credentials this way (https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#usernames-and-passwords):

`Jenkinsfile`:

```groovy
pipeline {
    ...
    environment {
        AUTH = credentials('artifactory-credentials-id') # as configured in the Jenkins web interface
    }
    ...
}
```

In `build.gradle`, you can use pick credentials from either `gradle.properties` for local builds, and environment variables for Jenkins builds:

```groovy
artifactory {
  contextUrl = "..."

  resolve {
    repository {
      repoKey = "..."
      username = hasProperty('artusr') ? project.property('artusr') : System.env["AUTH_USR"]
      password = hasProperty('artpass') ? project.property('artpass') : System.env["AUTH_PSW"]
    }
```

For local builds it is then possible to put the credentials in `~/gradle.properties`:

```
artusr=my-artifactory_user
artpass=my-secret-password
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but that will be like I need to configure the artusr and artpass in the .gradle folder of the project and not as a whole in the user folder, .gradle . So that will lead to commiting the code to vcs. Is there a way I could do this in the user's folder's . gradle folder so that it will be taking from there itself

Comment: Hi, there is no need to add the credentials to cvs. You can put them in your home directory `~/gradle.properties`. I've updated my answer to include this.